# aiogram Логика кода Вопрос новичка

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Доброго времени суток всем.
Пытаюсь написать бота, который будет вести табель времени.
Проблема следующая:
При команде start идет вывод обычного приветственного сообщения в конце которого говориться о том, чтобы юзер ввел свои ФИО.
Далее по логике это ФИО должен ловить хендлер без параметров.
Код:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def command_start_process(message: types.Message):
    response = await c.command_start(message=message)
    await message.reply(
        text=response["text"],
        parse_mode="HTML",
        reply=False
    )

    @dp.message_handler()
    async def name_and_fullname(message: types.Message):
        response = await c.message_main_menu_fullname(message=message)
        await message.reply(
            text=response["text"],
            parse_mode="HTML",
            reply_markup=response['markup'],
            reply=False
        )
```

Но помимо этого хендлера без параметров у меня есть еще два. Находятся они ниже, чем тот, о котором я писал ранее. Но почему-то именно второй или третий(они одинаковы) пустой хендлер ловит мое сообщение.
Вопрос в следующем: Как сделать так, чтобы первый пустой хендлер ловил именно ФИО, а два следующих пустых хендлера ловили именно время(время поступает при нажатие на кнопку)
Заранее благодарю за ответы.
Весь код:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def command_start_process(message: types.Message):
    response = await c.command_start(message=message)
    await message.reply(
        text=response["text"],
        parse_mode="HTML",
        reply=False
    )

    @dp.message_handler()
    async def name_and_fullname(message: types.Message):
        response = await c.message_main_menu_fullname(message=message)
        await message.reply(
            text=response["text"],
            parse_mode="HTML",
            reply_markup=response['markup'],
            reply=False
        )


@dp.message_handler(Text(contains=NAME_OBJECT['sz']))
async def sz_tec(message: types.Message):
    response = await c.come_and_leave(message=message)
    await message.reply(
        text=response["text"],
        parse_mode="HTML",
        reply_markup=response['markup'],
        reply=False
    )
@dp.message_handler(Text(contains=NAME_OBJECT['tec14']))
async def tec_14(message: types.Message):
    response = await c.come_and_leave(message=message)
    await message.reply(
        text=response["text"],
        parse_mode="HTML",
        reply_markup=response['markup'],
        reply=False
    )
@dp.message_handler(Text(contains=NAME_OBJECT['tec15']))
async def tec_15(message: types.Message):
    response = await c.come_and_leave(message=message)
    await message.reply(
        text=response["text"],
        parse_mode="HTML",
        reply_markup=response['markup'],
        reply=False
    )

@dp.message_handler(Text(contains=COME_AND_LEAVE['come']))
async def time_for_come_(message: types.Message):
    response = await c.time_for_come_or_leave()
    await message.reply(
        text='А сейчас выберите время',
        parse_mode="HTML",
        reply_markup=response['markup'],
        reply=False
    )

    @dp.message_handler()
    async def name_and_fullname(message: types.Message):
        await message.reply(
            text=f'Я записал Вас. Записанное время: {message.text}',
            parse_mode="HTML",
            reply_markup=response['markup'],
            reply=False
        )


@dp.message_handler(Text(contains=COME_AND_LEAVE['leave']))
async def time_for_leave(message: types.Message):
    response = await c.time_for_come_or_leave()
    await message.reply(
        text='А сейчас выберите время',
        parse_mode="HTML",
        reply_markup=response['markup'],
        reply=False
    )

    @dp.message_handler()
    async def name_and_fullname(message: types.Message):
        await message.reply(
            text=f'Я записал Вас. Записанное время: {message.text}',
            parse_mode="HTML",
            reply_markup=response['markup'],
            reply=False
    )
```

Comment: Благодарить на за что, потому что вопроса нет, на что отвечать - непонятно.

Comment: Упс, забыл задать вопрос. Отредактировал

Comment: вам нужно копать в сторону FSM. Их уже наотвечали на этом сайте кучу